# AWS (Windows 2012) unable to connect to APNS (Apple Push Notification Server)

Tags: java, ios, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to connect to the APNS server via Java using the com.notnoop.apns.APNS.jar.

```
public class ApplePushNotification {       
   static ApnsService apns = APNS.newService().withCert(Constants.CERT_PATH, Constants.CERT_PASSWORD).withSandboxDestination().build();

   public static void pushMSG(String msg, String token) {
      try{
          String payload=APNS.newPayload().sound("default").alertBody(msg).build();
          apns.push(token,payload);
      }
      catch(NetworkIOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

I have downloaded the APNS production certificate and converted into .p12 format and placed it in the server which is an AWS Windows 2012 machine. However, no push notifications are sent.

The same setup works on my local machine, which is a Windows 8 PC.

Answer (score 0):

```
static ApnsService apns = APNS.newService()
                              .withCert(Constants.CERT_PATH, Constants.CERT_PASSWORD)
                              .withProductionDestination()
                              .build()
```

I just changed from sandbox to production now its working....